# Can an Arduino Pro Mini interface with a full-sized WiFi shield?

Tags: shields, arduino-pro-mini, wires

We have an Arduino Pro Mini on a breadboard connected to a 9V battery and a sensor, reading data. We also have a full-sized [Adafruit WINC1500 WiFi Shield with PCB Antenna](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3653). I would like to know if they can be connected and, if so, how.

I understand that a shield is usually stacked on a similarly sized board, but can we place the shield on the breadboard with the Mini and use jumper wire to connect the necessary pins so the Mini can use the WiFi (actually, we want to write to the SD card on the WiFi shield)? If so, how would we know which pins are used, and would we need to provide additional power? Or is connecting a Mini to a full-sized shield a ridiculous idea?

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to know if they can be connected and, if so, how.

Yes.

> but can we place the shield on the breadboard

No, the pins are misaligned and won't plug in.

> and use jumper wire to connect the necessary pins so the Mini can use the WiFi

Yes - connect the jumper wires directly to the WiFi shield pins.

> If so, how would we know which pins are used,

Read the manual or schematic for your WiFi shield. It probably uses the SPI pins plus a few more.

> and would we need to provide additional power?

It will need a power connection, yes - though "extra" power? Not sure what you mean.

Comment: Thanks. By extra power, I meant would I need an additional power source or if the shield could share the 9V battery with the mini.

Comment: @EllenSpertus Throw your 9V battery away. It's useless, so don't even start to use it. Use an AA or AAA battery pack.